# How to extending CI3 $this->db

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I'm building a codeigniter 3(.1.9 older version) apps using mysql, I need to extend / override codeigniter **$this->db**,

so if myapps using

- **$this->db->insert**
- **$this->db->update**
- **$this->db->replace** and
- **$this->db->delete**

there will be a log in a file for CRUD actions.

Comment: can you describe you requirements a bit more. Something like [system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/) or some MySQL audit plugins might be a better solution.

Comment: What do you mean by `extending`? Creating another db connection? Because on database.php under config, `['default']` database config is defined as **`this->db`** or else you can define another db connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot Change/Modify/Replace Database classes.
According to CodeIgniter Official Documentation
"The Database classes can not be extended or replaced with your own classes. All other classes are able to be replaced/extended."

[You can check the Official Documentation here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).